# Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке при клике колесом мышки

Tags: jquery

Друзья, глупый вопрос, но прошу помочь.
Имеется объект, в данном случае тег абзаца.
Имеется три события: клик, дабл клик, клик колесом мыши.
как сделать так, чтоб именно клик колесом открывал ссылку в новой вкладке?

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var timeoutId;
    jQuery('p').click(function(){
        timeoutId = setTimeout('document.location.href = "https://www.yandex.ru/";', 500);
    }).dblclick(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        clearTimeout(timeoutId - 1);
        location.href = "https://www.google.ru/";
    });

    function middleClick(e) {
        if (e.which == 2) {
            location.href = "https://www.rambler.ru/" , '_blank';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    document.querySelector("p").addEventListener("mousedown", middleClick);

});


<p>Example</p>
```

Comment: `window.open(url, "_blank")` ?

Comment: да, чет я совсем затупил...спасибо большое.